# How to detect chrome version in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

My webapp need to depend on chrome browser, so when the app installs, i have to detect the chrome browser version in Nsis script.
I try to use the following script, but it does not work. The `$R0` is empty string.

```
!define CHROME "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome"
ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "${CHROME}" "UninstallString"
```

How to detect chrome version information in NSIS script ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the current user settings instead of the local machine (or in addition to the local machine if the resulting string is empty):

```
ReadRegStr $R0 HKCU "${CHROME}" "UninstallString"
```

Also you should not have a backslash at the beginning of the key path. Did you noticed a warning during the script compilation?

```
ReadRegStr: registry path name begins with '\', may cause problems
```